# searching through MOVIE databse using mysql and java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I created a table in my MySQL database that has the following columns:
movieID, title, genre, year, mpaaRating, director, company

I'm supposed to take user input of a movie name and search through the movie table and display all the information of the movie which are the categories above.  If the movie is not found, I display "movie not found"

my code so far is

```
System.out.print("Please enter the name of a movie you would like to search: ");
        String movieName = in.nextLine();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT movieID, title, genre, year, mpaaRating, director, company FROM MOVIES WHERE title = '" + movieName + "'");
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to query because I am getting an error when I search this way.
Also, I have no idea how to display the results or display "movie not found" if the search criteria doesn't match.  Do I just use an if statement for the latter part?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of error you are getting? show us the stacktrace.

Comment: [Obligatory SQL injection warning](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: It's giving me an SQLExeption so I'm guessing it's a syntax error in the 3rd line. @maxx777

Comment: @user3554599 show us more code and complete stacktrace. and you are advised to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE Operator for search as below

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT movieID, title, genre, year, mpaaRating, director, company FROM MOVIES WHERE title LIKE '%"+movieName+"%'");
```

Hope this helps.